# SAS EG fails without error when automated

Tags: sas

We have this odd error that we have been unable to find any information on. We have a bunch of SAS EG 6.1 projects automated being executed from VB scripts.

A few of these projects will fail in a particular way, during a long (can happen on something that takes less than 2 minutes so not that long) Proc SQL or data step, the program will simply stop, nothing extra will be written to the logs, any subsequent commands in the program wont be run. If there is more in the process flow, they will run as if nothing went wrong.
Every morning we have to open these projects and check to see if they "no-logged", if they did, we run them manually. This error NEVER occurs when running it manually.

We've looked into server load, network drops, timing with other jobs, nothing else seems to go on. I even ran SQL profiler during one of these issues, and it looks the same as when it succeeds.

EDIT: VB used to run SAS Project
(not actually js, just couldn't get it to paste nicely

```html
Option Explicit
Dim app
Call dowork
'shut down the app


Sub dowork()
    On Error Resume Next
    '----
    ' Start up Enterprise Guide using the project name
    '----
    Dim prjName
    Dim prjObject

    prjName = "\\Pioneer-rpt01\Analytics\07.MajorProjects\201909 Analytics DB\Populate_DataStore_JAMs_IntraDay.egp"    'Project Name
      
    Set app = CreateObject("SASEGObjectModel.Application.6.1")
    If Checkerror("CreateObject") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '-----
    ' open the project
    '-----
    Set prjObject = app.Open(prjName,"")
    If Checkerror("app.Open") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
        
    '-----
    ' run the project
    '-----
    prjObject.run
    If Checkerror("Project.run") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
            
    '-----
    ' Save the new project
    '-----
    prjObject.Save
    If Checkerror("Project.Save") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '-----
    ' Close the project
    '-----
    prjObject.Close
    If Checkerror("Project.Close") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
       
End Sub

Function Checkerror(fnName)
    Checkerror = False
    
    Dim strmsg
    Dim errNum
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        strmsg = "Error #" & Hex(Err.Number) & vbCrLf & "In Function " & fnName & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        'MsgBox strmsg  'Uncomment this line if you want to be notified via MessageBox of Errors in the script.
        Checkerror = True
    End If
         
End Function
```

Comment: Please specify how you start SAS EG 6.1 from VB script and why you don't start plain SAS code, exported from EG in batch.

Comment: We use JAMS software to manage our automation. JAMS will execute the "standard" VBScript for running SAS jobs. I will update the question with that code.